# Typescript, losing Zod and tRPC types across monorepo projects, types result in any

Tags: typescript, next.js, yarn-workspaces, zod, trpc.io

I am in a bit of a weird situation. For the past 2 weeks I've been trying to debug as to why I am losing types between my projects inside a monorepo. My backend exposes the types that my client uses, but for some reason, certain types just don't get across and become `any`. This has made me unable to develop anything on this project for a while. [I made a sample repo out of the issue to further showcase it.](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/monorepo-trpc-issue)

The project is built with `Yarn Workspaces` and it's structured as following

- `apps/site`, the NextJS client importing the tRPC `AppRouter`
- `apps/backend`, the express backend that is exposing the `AppRouter`
- `apps/config`, here are the base `tsconfig`s used throught the project
- `packages/frontend-shared`, not important for this issue, shared UI components

The problem can be found inside the client [in the `apps/site/src/lib/ApiProvider.ts`](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/monorepo-trpc-issue/blob/master/apps/site/src/lib/APIProvider.ts)

```js
// The type is imported directly from backend, here we use type alias to make it cleaner
import type { AppRouter, EmailType, ProfileType, Test } from "@company/backend/trpc";

export type { AppRouter } from "@company/backend/trpc";
import { inferProcedureOutput } from "@trpc/server";

// The type is inferred to any
// Also if you hover over the app router, the context is also any
type loginOutputType = inferProcedureOutput<AppRouter["user"]["login"]>;
//Profile type doesn't have test field but it lets me set it
const a: ProfileType = {};
a.test = false;

//Same as well here, but it errors out as it should
const b: EmailType = {};
b.test = false;

//
const t: Test = {}
```

The types for `tRPC` method output are inferred to `any` for some reason, the `const a` type is alias to `Profile` but the type checker doesn't complain even if I add fields that don't exist.

The `const b` and `const t` have correct typing

My setup is pretty standard as far as the typescript configuration, [I use this base `tsconfig`](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/monorepo-trpc-issue/blob/master/packages/tsconfig/base.json) which sets some sane defaults like `strict` and all of the other configs inherit from it

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've tried tinkering with the tsconfigs, redoing them entirely, tried deleting path aliases, cleaning the yarn cache, tried using project references from frontend to backend but I kept having the same issue

It's very difficult to debug why as there is only typescript magic happening here, no errors or anything of sorts I can look into, I followed the `tRPC` setup guide but for some reason, some setting or causing types to be broken.

I am 90% sure the issue is not in fact the `tsconfig`'s as I also copied entire setups from other people and it still resulted in the same type inference. I have no idea what else affects typescript in this way, my last resort seems to be to make the API layer into a package and use directly import it inside my packages, but that's hacky and would require quite a bit of refactoring, while I am 100% certain that my current setup should indeed work

Comment: I had the same issue, so I set up minimal working example and started adding code until types resulted in any. Turns out it was because I used `infer` in one of my custom types.

Comment: Faced a similar issue. I was using path alias to reference my backend types. The problem was that I was using path alias in the backend as well. Once I was using relative path in the backend the frontend got the types correctly.

Comment: @oae oh, that might be the issue, I got around it by importing the transpiled code in the /dist directly. It's a bit ugly but it got me out of this 1 month rut

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue. I had a monorepo setup, with 2 packages one `trpc-backend` and `mobile-app`. To fix this issue on the frontend app I had to add the `references` property to my frontend tsconfig.json to be

```json
{
 ...
 "references": [{ "path": "../trpc-backend" }] 
}
```

on doing this, you'll get a ts warning, saying the referenced project, must have `composite` set to true.
to fix this, go over to the backend code and add the composite property under `compilerOptions`
so...

```json
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "composite": true,
 }
}
```

and you're done

Answer (score 2):

Just crediting @oae's answer/comment, which solved the issue for me

> The problem was that I was using path alias in the backend as well. Once I was using relative path in the backend the frontend got the types correctly

Edit: but I think there is a more elegant solution, which is to directly emit js output files after transforming the aliased imports into relative ones, something which can be achieved with https://github.com/justkey007/tsc-alias, example:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

*In reference to [don duke's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75827377/19529774) answer*

Project references conflict with the `noEmit: true` flag in `tsconfig.json`, which is necessary for Webpack, Parcel, Rollup, etc.

Since you're using Zod types, I'm assuming these are declared in a separate package. In that case, **deleting** the `tsconfig.json` file (as advised in [this Turborepo post](https://turbo.build/blog/you-might-not-need-typescript-project-references)) in your `types` package fixes the typing issue while preserving `noEmit: true`