# tRPC AppRouter is defined as "any" on import with Turborepo

Tags: typescript, turborepo, trpc.io

I am currently using a monorepo with Turborepo to store all my microservices code in a single repository, each with a `package.json` and a `tsconfig.json`, all of them written in nodejs.

in each `tsconfig.json`, the config is identical

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18-strictest-esm",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@folder-a/*": ["./folder-a/*"], // masked
      "@folder-b/*": ["folder-b/*"] // masked
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

I have one service `A` as a tRPC server, and one service `B` as a tRPC client.

When I imported the type definition of `AppRouter` from `A` to `B`, the type definition becomes `any` in `B` when it is properly typed in `A`.

[image: Reference pic here.]

I researched about it and found similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185198/typescript-losing-zod-and-trpc-types-across-monorepo-projects-types-result-in), and it seems like path alias may cause this issue.

Is there any solution/alternate cause to this

Comment: Btw to anyone visiting this question, as no one has an apparent fix for this yet, I have since switched to using Nx as the monorepo and it's working fine for me.